# Inserir um elemento em um array que contem um objeto

Tags: javascript, json, array, vue.js

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço pra inserir um elemento dentro de um objeto de um array, no caso, quando faço a adição com o código abaixo, o elemento é inserido como outro index:

```
 this.array = [];
 this.array.push(email);
 this.array.push({ Mensagem: res.data[0].Mensagem });
```

O retorno que obtenho é este aqui:

```
[
  {
    "CodigoPostagem": 25,
    "DataMensagem": "2017-06-28T14:35:00",
    "Emitente": "Item",
    "Titulo": "Mensagem número 25",
    "Visualizado": false
  },
  {
    "Mensagem": "Teste"
  }
]
```

O "email" possui o item acima, queria somente de inserir o retorno de uma api dentro daquele objeto.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Queres adicionar esse objeto com a `Mensagem` ao objeto do `email`? é isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode somente atribuir antes de fazer `push`:

```
this.array = [];
email.mensagem = res.data[0].Mensagem;
this.array.push(email);
```